# Evaluate the limit of the form $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_o+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, limits, continuity

Limits of the form $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_o+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$$ occur frequently in calculus.
Evaluate this limit for the given $x_0$ and function $f$:

$f(x)=3x-4, \ \ \ \ \ \ x_0=2$

---

Okay so I know I have to replace $x_0 $ with 2, but what do I do with  $3x-4$?

Comment: $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x_o+h)-f(x_0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{3*(x_o+h)-4-(3*x_0-4)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{3*h}{h}=3$

Comment: This limit is, by definition, the derivative of $f$ at $x_0$. To answer your exact question you replace $x$ with $2+h$.

Comment: So the limit would be 3?

Comment: Note that $f$ is an operation, not a function. In this case, $f(x)=3x-4$ mean s that $f$ is equivalent to "triple a number and decrease by 4". So the expression $f(x_0+h)$ would mean "triple [$x_0+h$] and decrease by 4".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion lies in the notation of $f(x)$.

To apply this notation within your context (the limit definition of a derivative), we find:

$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{3*(2+h)-4-(3*2-4)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{3h}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} 3=3$.

The first step I just plug in. The second is algebra. The final step is the property of limits that shows that the limit of a constant is that constant.